# combinatorial argument with catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Is induction the correct way to approach this combinatorial proof? I'm lost at where to start.

[image]

Comment: Consider the operation between the expressions in parentheses: where does the last one occur? For example, for $((a_1\cdot_1 a_2)\cdot_3 (a_3 \cdot_2 a_4))\cdot_5 (a_5 \cdot_4 a_6)$, the last multiplication is $\cdot_5$. Representing multiplications as binary trees may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using balanced parenthesis as the representation for $n$ pairs the structure should be in the format 
$$(B)E$$ 
where $B$ and $E$ will have total $(n-1)$ pairs.

How many ways can it be arranged? $(B,E) = (0,n-1) \dots (n-1,0)$ Direct substitution will give the Catalan recursive definition

$$ C_n = \sum\limits_{b+e=n-1} C_bC_e $$